# What's diffused diode resistor?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components

[Datasheet](https://dtsheet.com/doc/1558311/75017285)

[image: The schematic containing diffused diode resistor]

What is diffused diode resistor? (p. 22 in the datasheet)

What does it do and how does it work?

Edit: The only thing I've managed to find on Google is that it's somehow related to ESD protection.

See [this link](http://anlage.umd.edu/RCM/ToddFirestoneMSThesisUnivofMaryland.pdf) (page number 84 written in the document and 99 in PDF readers)

[image: some ESD info]

Comment: I don't see how the link is relevant to the question. What page should we be looking at?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added the page number.

Comment: My *guess* is that it's a JFET being used as a resistor. Its resistance would vary slightly with the input voltage, so perhaps it's used to get a quicker discharge than charge?

Comment: What you have listed as a datasheet doesn't appear to be a datasheet but a selection table.

Comment: @Martin [Does this help?](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/motorola/_appNotes/Designing_Diffused_Integrated_Circuit_Resistors_Dec1962.pdf)

Comment: It has been a while so I'll leave writing an answer to the experts, but IIRC diffusion resistors are N+, N- or P+ doped resistors with a lower sheet resistivity. This makes them ideal when using around transistors. Basically you have an alloy used in a transistor with different temperature characteristics than a 'normal' one.

Comment: If you diffuse n+ into a p- substrate or well you get a diffused diode where the resistor is also the diode's cathode. If you diffuse p+ into n- you get a diffused diode where the resistor is also the diode's anode. And note that the diode can be diffused into a well that is at a different voltage from the substrate.

Comment: Thank you very much, JRE. I've compared diode resistor that I've posted. The diode is oriented other way around and is connected to ground. Does the oppsite diode orientation mean that the semiconductor types are also opposite? And does the connection to ground mean that either the entire substrate of the chip is connected to ground or the diffused diode resistor is isolated from the rest of substrate by two PN junctions connected, such that it forms two diodes connected back to back and the piece of substrate containing the diffused diode resistor is connected to ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The leftmost resistor, the POLY, is conductive gate oxide deposited atop THICK oxide, to withstand high voltages. At 100 ohms and 1,000 volts, there will be 10 amps dumped thru that first diode into the VDD, and probably into substrate if the diode is 3_layer.
- The diffused_diode resistor has the task of dumping ESD energy into the substrate. The 2nd terminal of the diode is the Substrate (ground for this process) and by placing a large number of Substrate Contacts at some distance form the "Diode" anode contacts, the ESD energy is again steered into the substrate.